# How to undo Git Conflict Resolution

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a situation where there is a file with

```
apple
orange
bananna
```

This was committed into `Branch A`. `Branch B` was checked out. It did not contain this file. A duplicate file was created with some differences. The file was committed.

The file in `Branch B` had

```
bear
wolf
tiger
```

`Branch A` was checked out. `git merge B` was executed with a merge conflict. `git checkout --ours file.txt` was used to resolve the conflict

After some work had been done, it was realized that what was correct is `Branch B` version:

```
bear
wolf
tiger
```

Trying to run git merge again doesn't create a new conflict resolution. It appears that the only way to merge the changes in is to modify the file again.

Is there a way to accomplish this without modifying the file? Or a way to find the resolution was resolved this way? The history for that commit doesn't show that the conflict was resolved this way.

EDIT:
Here is a test script emulating the problem

```
mkdir git_test
cd git_test
git init

echo "README" > readme.md
git add readme.md
git commit -m "Init"

git branch a
git checkout a

echo -e "apples\moranges\banannas" > file.txt

git add file.txt
git commit -m "Checkin file.txt on branch a"

git checkout master
git branch b
git checkout b

echo -e "bears\nwolf\ntigers" > file.txt

git add file.txt
git commit -m "Checkin file.txt on branch b"

git checkout a
git merge b
git checkout --ours file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "Merged branches"
```

Comment: For my understanding could you answer the following. Is file.txt which you committed in Branch A and Branch B is a new file with the same name right? Can you share the result of the git checkout --ours file.txt after the merge git merge B?

Comment: You get the following result in the conflict when merged               <<<<<<< HEAD
apple
orange
banana
=======
bear
wolf 
tiger
>>>>>>> refs/heads/branchB

Comment: `git checkout --ours file.txt` changes the file to apple
orange
bananna.